# jQuery map splitting the value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery map is returning : `data:["1", "8", "5", ".", "9", "0"]` when the input `val` is `185.90` - **why the value is being splited?**

The code:

```
var $cel = $.map(
  $('td:nth-child(' + (i + 2) + ') input').each(function() {
      $(this).val();
  }).val(), function(value) {
      return value;
 );

 return {

        data: $cel
  };
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that data? Please can you add some more explanations...

Comment: @Lix - I want to return full value `185.90`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val()` returns the `value` of the first matched element. And that `value` is a `string`,or in other words *array of chars*.That is why, you are iterating through the chars of the `value`'s string.

Probably, you want this:

```
var $cel = $.map( $('td:nth-child('+(i+2)+') input').get(), function(elem) {
  return +elem.value;   //'+' will convert string to number
});
```

Comment: you sure this is correct? `$cel` not returning anything when using the code above

Comment: @NewUser Then your selector probably is wrong, look at [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/6UxVc/1/)

Comment: got it - error in select. Thanks for the example. Is there any way that you can return the values without the `"` ?

Comment: thanks. Never seen that before. What is the principle behind this?

Comment: @NewUser It has same effect as `Number(str)`, only it is much more faster.

Answer (score 0):

Because map returns an array. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/
not a full number.